# How to calculate the bandwidth bound for a GPU

Tags: performance, gpu, gpgpu

I am wanting to calculate the theoretical bandwidth bound for my GPU for transfer from
GPU global memory to registers.

Details :

```
1. GPU -- Nvidia GTX 680
2. Measured global bandwidth -- 123 GB/sec
3. Data size -- image of size 9216x9216 (1-channel)
```

Please help. Is any more information need to calculate the bound?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretical bandwidth for the GK104 is 192 GB/s. You can find that in the Kepler white paper here: http://www.geforce.com/Active/en_US/en_US/pdf/GeForce-GTX-680-Whitepaper-FINAL.pdf